# Add a default row to the top of an ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView that is populated from an SqlDataSource with specific values.

How would I add a default row to the top of myGridView?

And I want the the default row to have text 'All'

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPoints"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_userPoints"
    AllowPaging="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="id_point,title"
    BorderWidth="0px"
    Width="100%"
    GridLines="None">

    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField
            CommandName="selectedPoint"
            DataTextField="title"
            ButtonType="Link" />
    </Columns>

    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></RowStyle>
</asp:GridView>



<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource_userPoints" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:TipTourConnectionString %>' 
    SelectCommand ="SELECT 
                        id_point, 
                        title, 
                        body

                    FROM tt_point

                    WHERE id_user = @id_user">

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter 
            QueryStringField="id_user" 
            DefaultValue="0" 
            Name="id_user">
        </asp:QueryStringParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way in this scenario would be to add it with the SQL statement.

This assumes id_point is a numeric field.  If not, remove the convert function

```
SELECT 'All' AS id_point, 'All' AS title, 'All' AS body
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, id_point), title, body FROM tt_point WHERE id_user = @id_user
```

Comment: Anyways, can someone explain how this could be done with markup or in the code behind

Comment: This is probably the easiest way, THANKS AGAIN @Clint B

Comment: There isn't a row.Add() method for the grid.  So the best way to do it in code behind is to bind a DataTable to the grid.  Before doing the bind you would add the row to the DataTable.  But since you are binding the data to the grid with the DataSourceID attribute that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Replace This

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="selectedPoint" DataTextField="title" ButtonType="Link" />
```

with this

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="selectedPoint" DataTextField="title" ButtonType="Link" HeaderText="All" />
```

I added `HeaderText="All"` to your `ButtonField`
Make sure in your gridview this is there `ShowHeader="true"`

If you want to add 2 rows bind your gridview like this

```
strcon = "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=testDB;trusted_Connection=yes";    
private void BindGridData()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id_point,title,body FROM tt_point WHERE id_user = @id_user", connection);
        string userid = "0";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_user", userid);
        SqlDataAdapter daimages = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        daimages.Fill(dt);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["id_point"] = "All";
        dr["title"] = "All";
        dr["body"] = "All";
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
        DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
        dr1["id_point"] = "All";
        dr1["title"] = "All";
        dr1["body"] = "All";
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr1, 1);            
        gvPoints.DataSource = dt;
        gvPoints.DataBind();
    }
```

call this method on page load like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGridData();
        }
    }
```

Here in `strcon` database name is `testDB` replace with your databasename

Remove this from gridview **DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_userPoints"**

Comment: that makes it look more like a header title, what if i had 2 default values to add

Comment: @blitzeus 2 default values, you mean row?

Comment: @blitzeus i modified my answer, please check